# igraph network graph with color-gradient bar

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to to add color-gradient bar below the network graph I draw using igraph. For some reason, the axis label of the color-gradient bar can't be shown. However , when I draw the color-gradient bar alone without the network graph, the axis label is perfectly shown. Any suggestion ?

```
colorstrip <- function(colors) {
  count <- length(colors)
  m <- matrix(1:count, count, 1)
  par(mai=c(5, 50, 30, 50), cex.axis=2, ann=T, tck=-1)
  image(m, col=colors, ylab="", axes=FALSE)
  axis(side=3, at=seq(from=-0.165, to=1.22, by=0.332),
       labels=letters[1:5])
}

library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(10)

pdf("test_igraph.pdf", width=200, height=200)
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2), heights=c(2,0.5))
plot(g)
colorstrip(c("red", "mediumseagreen", "yellow", "blue"))
dev.off()
```

[Original code was here](https://gist.github.com/6911981)

Comment: Please include the code in the post next time, and make sure that the code actually works. It also helps if you get rid of unnecessary details, to make the code smaller. Then people will be more willing to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are there, but they are very tiny. Zoom in in your PDF viewer and then you will see them.

[image: bad plot]

The reason for them being tiny is that the plot itself is huge. For `pdf()` `width` and `height` is in inches, so you have a 200 in times 200 in figure. The solution is to make the figure smaller (or the letters bigger, but I guess you don't want to have a huge figure anyway):

```
colorstrip <- function(colors) {
  count <- length(colors)
  m <- matrix(1:count, count, 1)
  par(mai=c(0.2, 2, 1, 2), cex.axis=2, ann=T, tck=-1)
  image(m, col=colors, ylab="", axes=FALSE)
  axis(side=3, at=seq(from=-0.165, to=1.22, by=0.332),
       labels=letters[1:5])
}

library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(10)

pdf("test_igraph.pdf", width=7, height=7)
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2), heights=c(2,0.5))
plot(g)
colorstrip(c("red", "mediumseagreen", "yellow", "blue"))
dev.off()
```

[image: good plot]

So this has nothing to do with igraph. Actually, even if you just plot the color strip, you will not see the labels.